# squaring matrix and running time

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer, big-o

I can show that the square of matrix A which is 2 * 2 is O(n^log5) by showing that it needs just 5 multiplication. Till now I have no problem, but after when I want to explain 2 reasons why we can not generalize it for other cases of squaring(different n*n size) I can just come up with one as follow:

the first reason that I could come up with was I multiplied for example 3*3 matrix with itself and concluded that at least it has 6 multiplication so its running time is at least O(n^log6) which n^epsalon greater that O(n^log5) so it is slower and we can not generalize O(n^log5) for all cases . Now I need another reason but I can not come up with any idea how to explain the second reason can anyone help(I need just a hint to come up with an idea)?

Comment: Squaring a matrix of any fixed size takes time O(1), since only a fixed number of multiplications are required. Saying that the runtime is O(n^log 5) is technically correct, but your reasoning for concluding it is wrong.

Comment: Thanks, by strassen decomposition I know that every matrix multiplication is T(n)=7T(n/2)+n^2 and also by squaring 2*2 matrix I know that it O(n^log5) now if I show that other cases are T(n)>=6T(n/2)+n^2 then I showed that I cannot generalize O(n^log5). Now I am confused could you please explain more?

Comment: What do you mean by "squaring 2x2 matrix I know that it O(n^log 5)?" Where does the log 5 come from?

Comment: Because if you multiply A*A at the end you will have 5 multiplication and the additions takes n^2 so we have 5T(n/2)+n^2(exactly the same thing that we do for strassen)

Comment: The 5 in the Strassen recurrence doesn't mean "five multiplications;" it means "five subproblems." In the case of a 2 x 2 matrix, there are only five multiplications required, but there are no subproblems. Again - for any fixed-size matrix, the runtime of a multiply is O(1).

Comment: So now imagine that we can technically say O(n^log5) . How can I show that I cannot generalize it for squaring matrix of size n?(I know I should find things that I am doing in squaring a 2x2 that stop it from turning into a recursive step for square arrays. But I can not find those things)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot possibly derive the running time in big-o notation from examples. Big-O notation tells us something about how the complexity of an algorithm scales with increasing arguments (in this case the matrix size n) so if you really wanted to approximate it experimentally you would have to at least calculate the running time of several test sizes.

But I doubt you can find the optimal way to square 100x100 matrices by hand... It is actually a difficult problem. What we know for sure is, that it is no more complex than a matrix-matrix-product. For those we have a lower bound of Omega(n^2) as we have to look at every entry of the matrix at least once. And we have an upper bound for the (theoretical) perfect algorithm of approximately O(n^2.3729) because there is an algorithm known with that complexity. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Algorithms_for_efficient_matrix_multiplication )

Incidentally 2.3729 < log6 which you suggested to be the minimum - which does not contradict the statement, that you might need 6 multiplications for a 3x3 matrix, because once again: O-notation only cares about asymptotic behaviour of the running time as n gets large - and not about any particular running times of individual n.